# How to set custom font and weight (style) to UInavigationbar title

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, custom-font

How to set custom font name and custom font weight (font style) for UINavigationBar title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UIFontDescriptor` as `Font Name` and `Font Size`

`UIFontDescriptor.fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits` as font style (Bold, Italic, ...)

**Swift 2.x:**

```
let fontDec = UIFontDescriptor(name: "FontName", size: 20)
fontDec.fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(.TraitBold)
let font = UIFont(descriptor: fontDec, size: 20)

self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: font,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()]
```

> Maybe performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

For swift 5.x

```
let titleNavBar = UIFontDescriptor(name: "Futura", size: 35).withSymbolicTraits(.traitBold)

navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.font: UIFont(descriptor: titleNavBar!, size: 35), .foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this code.** Swift 3x

This could be a better approach to set nanvigationBar title font and Style.

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.ANY COLOUR, NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name:"FontName-FontStyle", size: ANY SIZE)!]
```

**Some Font Styles:**

```
    Regular,Bold,BoldItalic,CondensedBlack,CondensedBold,Italic,Light,LightItalic,Thin,ThinItalic,UltraLight,UltraLightItalic
```

**Note:** Font style varies from font to font!

Comment: hassle free approach and this is a very basic one which we used in Objective-C also!

Answer (score -1):

Swift 4x:

let newFont = UIFont(name: "FontName", size: 15)
newFont?.fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(.traitBold)