# Navigation Bar Title - Change Font without changing size

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I'm having trouble to change both the regular and large titles of my Navigation Bar. I only want to change the font, without interfering on the font size. I tried getting the pointSize, but it's not available for NavBar titles. How can I do it?

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: Please share what you already tried with `pointSize`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set custom font and weight (style) to UInavigationbar title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501923/how-to-set-custom-font-and-weight-style-to-uinavigationbar-title)

Comment: @Carlos check out the updated answer:)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change **only** font size. Since the font represents both size and the font itself.

**Solution**: change the font (both size and font) but set the default size. If you haven't made any changes to your project regarding the size then it's **17** by default. I tested it out and found it out.

So here is what you can do:

```
let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: YourFontOfSize(size: 17.0)
    ]

navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes
```

Hope it helps! Please let me know if it worked.

**UPDATE:**
Navigation bar also has a property called `.largeTitleTextAttributes`. So you can do the same as I did for `.titleTextAttributes`: Find out the default size by just trying to set the system font with sizes: 15, 16, 17 etc. And then when the size matches you will know which is the default size. And then apply your custom font using the default size that you found out.

Comment: He is worried about the large titles size.. have you tested it with large titles?

Comment: reasonable. but he can do it himself. It's easy. you just sit and change the fonts from 15 to 20. I think we shouldn't do this for him. he can figure it out using my example. Sorry, Carlos :).

Comment: I guess you are not aware of https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/large-titles-ios-11/

Comment: Sorry, but I am. Why did you think that not? Maybe I'm missing something in this conversation, please let me know since I don't understand your concern. @MilanNosáľ

Comment: setting attributes is pretty easy.. but how would you know when to change the size to the proper size for large titles? etc. just setting the title size through attributes is more or less trivial in comparison with the challenge of dealing with large title/normal title changes.. if the OP is not absolute novice, he should be able to pretty easily google up the part you provided in the answer.. but I expect the question is here because what is he really dealing with is the second part, the challenging one

Comment: hmm. maybe I'm getting you wrong. But may I ask 1 question. Do you know about `.largeTitleTextAttributes` property of the navigationBar? @MilanNosáľ

Comment: no.. and I believe that is what should definitely be in your answer!

Comment: editing then. thanks for your help understanding the concern:)

Answer (score 0):

Well There is a way but not programmatically. You can manually set the different font sizes from the utility panes in attribute inspector.

[image: ][]